# How to distribute accounts on users equally based on a time zone in mysql?

Tags: mysql, distribution, quicksort

I have 1000 account. each account has account_name, account_id, time_zone_id

I want to generate activities for every account to 3 users.

So I will need to generate 333 activities for used #10 and 333 for user #11 and 334 for user #12. But I need to make sure that the time zone is distributed equally. so if I have 200 account in a time zone 18 and 400 account in time zone 10 and 200 in time zone 7 and 200 in time zone 39 then I want to make sure I distribute those new activities for the users equally

I have tried something like this as a select to get the count and see if I am going the correct direction

```
SELECT count(ac.account_id) AS total, ac.time_zone_id,
(SELECT user_id FROM users where team_id = 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) AS user_id
FROM accounts AS ac
GROUP BY ac.time_zone_id
```

this created the activities but it is not equal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would return a user_no ( 10-12 ) for each account.
It sorts by time_zone_id and then uses the mod function to pick each of the three users in turn (user 10 for the first result, 11 for second, 12 for third, 10 for fourth and so on).

```
set @r = 0 ;
select 
  @r:=@r+1 row_no, 
  account_id, 
  account_name,
  mod(@r,3)+10 user_no 
from 
  account 
order by 
  time_zone_id
```

**Revision**

you can get users in a similar way

```
set @ur = 0;
select 
  @ur:=@ur+1 user_row_no,
  user_id
from users
  where team_id = 4
```

**Revised again**

It would be something like this

**Make some sample data**

```
create table users( user_id int, team_id int) ;
insert into users select 2,4 
union select 3,4
union select 1,2
union select 7,4
union select 6,4;

create table account ( account_id int, 
                      account_name varchar(20),
                      time_zone_id varchar(3),
                      assigned_to int
                      );

insert into account(account_id ,account_name,time_zone_id)
select 1,'Janice','pst'
union select 2,'Jonny','gmt'
union select 3,'Jane','gmt'
union select 4,'Janet','pst'
union select 5,'James','gmt';
```

**Make a table to pop the users in that we are interested in** 
(could/should be a temp_table)

```
create table temp_user( id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
                        user_id int
                       );


insert into temp_user( user_id ) 
select user_id 
from users 
where team_id = 4;
```

**The update**

```
set @r=0;

update account join 
(
    select 
      @r:=@r+1 row_no, 
      account_id, 
      account_name,
      assigned_to
    from 
      account 
    order by 
      time_zone_id
  ) x 
on x.account_id = account.account_id
join
  temp_user 
  on

    temp_user.id=(1+ mod(row_no,(select count(*) from temp_user)))
  set account.assigned_to = temp_user.user_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/164733/10

Comment: Thank you. I shouyld have mentioned that user 10, 11, 12 I posted for the sake of the question and it is not real. there are many users in the database but I want to distribute the activities on all the users in team_id = 4

Comment: +1 -- nice answer to original question -- if different users exist, cannot guarantee distribution between time zones -- what if you have 10 users and only 5 records in a specific time zone...  This might be best handled in your presentation logic...

Comment: @Ian Kenney   How can I execute this update without a synax error?   Update accounts AS ac
INNER JOIN (
set @r = 0 ;
SELECT
  @r:=@r+1 row_no, 
  account_id, 
  account_name,
  mod(@r,3)+10  AS user_no
from 
  accounts 
order by 
  time_zone_id) AS t ON t.account_id = ac.account_id
SET  ac.assigned_to = t.user_no

Comment: you would need to put the set @r=0; right at the beginning of the query (before "update accounts")

Comment: Thank you sir :)  If there a way to do it if I was to do the same thing without knowing the user_ids?  so If I have 100 users